# How to split this list into words & find most common top 5 words & tags in python?

Tags: python

```
s=['how are you r',
 'many many happy returns of the day',
 'lets go for a walf']
```

I have tried like below-

```
from collections import Counter 

split_it =[i.split('\t')[0] for i in s] 
Counter = Counter(split_it) 
most_occur = Counter.most_common(5) 

print(most_occur)
```

The output is with sentence occurrences but not words & I don't have idea about how to build code for tags.How to code for top 5 tags & words?

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Define `tags`. You seem to be distinguishing them from `words` but the distinction is opaque.

Comment: None of the sentences in your example contain tabs. Try `i.split()` instead of `i.split('\t')`.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_text_processing/python_tagging_words.htm see this link,,i think you'll be cleared about tags

Answer (score 2):

When you split the sentences you get a list of lists, over which you then count appearances (of the nested list). You should flatten it. Also, you should be splitting by space and not tab:

```
s = ['how are you r',
     'many many happy returns of the day',
     'lets go for a walf']
 
from collections import Counter 

flattened = [item for i in s for item in i.split()]
Counter = Counter(flattened) 
most_occur = Counter.most_common(5) 

print(most_occur)
```

To get only the words you could iterate the result and take only the term part of the tuple:

```
print([t for t,n in most_occur])
```

Comment: Thanks.it works. how could i have the output without occurences? like 
word1,word2,word3

Comment: @Kheya_COU - If this answer solved your question please consider marking question as solved

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean about tags. I don't see any tags in your example.

your `i.split('\t')[0] for i in s` splits on a tab ('\t') on only the first item in each sentence but s doesn't contain any tabs.

you can split on space `[i.split() for i in s]` - you will get lists of lists though.

My advice is to break this up into steps - look at what split_it returns and evaluate whether that was expected.

if you only want words and are not interested in sentences, then you need to break apart the sentences into words then put all those words into a another list.

in explicit terms:

```
    my_new_list=[]
    for sent in s:
        words=sent.split()
        for word in words:
            my_new_list.append(word)
    
    counts = Counter(my_new_list).most_common(5)

print(counts)
```

This will give you individual word counts.

Comment: Thanks. see this link given below & you'll be cleared about tags.https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_text_processing/python_tagging_words.htm

Comment: pos tagging is a preprocessing step. you can use NLTK/spaCy/CoreNLP to get info on parts of speech. Have you been taught anything about this kind of parsing?

Comment: The pos tags in your example are returned as list of tuples. Separate the tuples and aggregate them.

Comment: nope.I don't have idea about these kind of parsing.Take me as a beginner.I am working on my assignment.Help me if you can. & how will i print the words without occurrences? like word1,word2,word3?

Comment: well words without occurrences are just a list of unique words. so set(my_new_list) will get you a list of unique words. In order to use the nltk pos tagger you follow the instructions you linked to and apply it to each sent in s. this will produce a list of lists of tuples. to aggregate them you do the same thing as above - for tup in list_of_tups: my_new_list.append(tup) - now you should have a bag of tuples. to aggregate the second element in each tuple, you need to index it: tag_only_list = [ item[1] for item in my_new_list] - now you can use the count function you used before.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm now trying on it.

Comment: sorry for bothering you again.You misunderstood about my question.how to print top 5 words without showing their occurences? I searched a lot but unable to find the answer.Please help

Comment: for the output in counts, loop over the tuples and extract the second item: for item in counts: words = [tup[1] for tup in item]